How to write script when not allowed to use backticks, &&, || or ;
Write a bash script that changes the owner of the file hello to betty only if it is owned by the user guillaume.
The file hello will be in the working directory
The script should not be more than two lines long and You are not allowed to use backticks, &&, || or ;
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(stat -c '%U' hello)" = "guillaume" ] then chown betty hello


Is this a question, or are you looking for feedback on your solution?

Note that we generally frown on folks dumping exercises in here as opposed to making your own attempt at a solution and asking about a problem you encountered yourself in the course thereof. (Also, there's a requirement that questions be practical in nature; the only circumstances I can think of when one would encounter these requirements in practice relate to trying to circumvent badly-thought-out security measures; the practice of pentesting is a separate field from software development, and only the latter is in-scope here).

I actually posted an exercise and I posted what I attempted to do which did not work. The main purpose of my question is to learn the logic behind writing scripts without using backticks, &&, || or ; so that I can confidently answer questions without posting them here

semicolon or newline is required before then. You're missing fi.

Learn to check your code at https://shellcheck.net before posting. Be sure to include #!/bin/bash (or whatever you are using) as the first line. If you still have problems, post the shellcheck corrected code with a note that you have used it. For beginners, the corrections offered by shellcheck may be a little obscure. Search the internet with the provided warning/error messages and hopefully you can figure it out. Good luck

Also note that the $( someCmd(s) ) part of your posted solution provides the same result as code listed in backticks (\someCmd(s)`), Both are known as command-substitution, The $(...)form is considered modern/preferred and is easily nestable, while the`...`` form is the lowest common denominator version, for some considered the basis of "portable code" because it is supported back to the original Bourne Shell of the the 1970s(?). Proper nesting of backtics requires quoting. Depending on the requirements of your work projects you may have to decide to use one over the other.

AND as you are prohibited from using ;, you'll need to put your then on a separate line, as well as fi I can't illustrate that in comments. /-;!

The solution using find is preferable, but I think that this satisfies your specification: eval $'[[ $(stat -c \'%U\' hello) == guillaume ]] \046\046 chown betty hello'

sudo find hello -prune -user guillaume -exec chown betty {} +


Thank you, it worked. Is there any material that explains how to achieve this kind of script. I am a beginner

man find would be the place to start. Or if you want a scripting language designed to enable scripts with conditional logic and flow control embedded in a single argument vector, then the appropriate shell is not sh or bash but execline
